# Moq keeps throwing null reference exception

Tags: c#, moq

I am new to Moq having used Rhino mocks for a while. I am trying to stub a method so that is returns the information I expect but the actual line of code when running the test returns a null reference exception. Am I missing something obvious here? Below is my code:

```
    public void GetResSystemClients(ResSystem resSystem)
    {
        ResSystemDetail = new ResSystemDetails() {ResSys = resSystem};

//RETURNS NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION
        var resClients = FileReader.ReadFile((c) => c.Where(x =>
            x.ReservationSystem.Replace(" ", "").ToLowerInvariant().Contains(resSystem.ToString().ToLowerInvariant())));

        ResSystemDetail.ResSystemClients = resClients
            .Select(y => new ResSystemClient() {ClientCode = y.ClientCode, ClientName = y.ClientName})
            .OrderBy(z => z.ClientCode).ToList();
    }
```

Test Code

```
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        mockFileReader = new Mock<IClientLookUpFileReader>(MockBehavior.Default);
        sut = new ClientLookupModel();
    }
    [TestCase(ResSystem.Test)]
public void When_GetResSystemCalled_With_ResSystem_Return_CorrectClients(ResSystem system)
    {
        //Arrange
        mockFileReader.Setup(x =>
                x.ReadFile(It.IsAny<Func<List<ExtraClientInfo>, IEnumerable<ExtraClientInfo>>>()))
            .Returns(new List<ExtraClientInfo>
            {
                new ExtraClientInfo
                {
                    ClientName = "Test",
                    ClientCode = "XX"
                },
                new ExtraClientInfo
                {
                    ClientName = "Test1",
                    ClientCode = "X1"
                },
                new ExtraClientInfo
                {
                    ClientName = "Test2",
                    ClientCode = "X2"
                },

            });

        //Act
        sut.GetResSystemClients(system);
    }
```

Read file code

```
    public interface IClientLookUpFileReader
{
    T ReadFile<T>(Func<List<ExtraClientInfo>, T> predicateFunc);
}

public class ClientLookUpFileReader : IClientLookUpFileReader
{
    private const string filePath = "D:/PersistedModels/ClientInfo.json";

    T IClientLookUpFileReader.ReadFile<T>(Func<List<ExtraClientInfo>, T> predicateFunc)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            var clientInfoList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<ExtraClientInfo>>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath));
            return predicateFunc(clientInfoList);
        }

        throw new Exception($"File not found at path {filePath}");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not even using the mock `mockFileReader`. I don't know how Rhino works, but with moq you need to use the object that you `Setup` in place of your implementation.

Comment: How is FileReader initialised in ClientLookupModel ?

Comment: @auburg - I feel silly now! I forgot the new keyword!

Comment: @TheKeyboarder fair enough but be aware that if you're new-ing up a FileReader internally in your class then you can't mock it.

Comment: Yea. I will mock it now and remove the new it was just to prove it wasn't the setup in moq